# Angular: is it possible to bundle attribute bindings in a template, similar as ng-templates for HTML-elements?

Tags: html, angular, data-binding, attributes, ng-template

Is it possible to combine multiple attribute-bindings within the HTML of an Angular component to prevent duplicated code?

For example, we currently have a component which has a button and an anchor like this:

```
<ng-template #button>
  <button [class]="classes"
          (click)="onClick($event)"
          [attr.disabled]="disabled">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="buttonContent"></ng-template>
  </button>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #anchor>
  <a [class]="classes"
     (click)="onClick($event)"
     [attr.disabled]="disabled"
     [href]="href">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="buttonContent"></ng-template>
  </a>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #anchorWithoutHref>
  <a [class]="classes"
     (click)="onClick($event)"
     [attr.disabled]="disabled">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="buttonContent"></ng-template>
  </a>
</ng-template>
```

As you can see, we have `[class]="classes" (click)="onClick($event)" [attr.disabled]="disabled"` on all three variants. Is it possible to create some kind of template or anything that's re-usable, so these attribute-bindings are only done on one place?

(We use Angular version 15.1.3.)

---

EDIT: `classes`; `disabled`; and `onClick(...)` are values/getters in my `button.component.ts` (and `disabled` is an `@Input` as well):

```
get classes(): string {
   let classesBuilder = new ClassesBuilder();
   ...
   return classesBuilder.toString();
}
```

```
private _disabled: boolean = false;

@Input()
set disabled(value: BooleanInput) {
  this._disabled = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
}

get disabled(): boolean {
  return this._disabled;
}
```

```
onClick($event: MouseEvent) {
  if (this.href && (!this.useButtonClick || $event.ctrlKey || $event.shiftKey)) {
    return; // Default behaviour
  }
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
  if (!this.disabled) {
    this.buttonClick.emit();
  }
}
```

This `disabled` is used in a few places within if-checks (like the onClick above, but also some other functions).

So the Directive approach suggested by *@WouterSpaak* does sound promising, and would indeed work if I could have moved the entire functionality/values to that directive. But if I want to pass these values above from my `button.component.ts` to the Directive, [I think I still need duplicated attributes to pass that data to the Directive](https://medium.com/@svsh227/pass-data-to-custom-directive-from-component-html-in-angular-2-application-bf08904da164), making it redundant in my case..

Comment: are these three sharing same logic and classnames?

Comment: @Chellappanவ They're all three in the same Angular component and use the same typescript methods/variables for their bindings indeed. The only difference is that the top is a button and the bottom two are anchors; and the middle anchor has `[href]` and bottom anchor not. The `class`, `click`, and `attr.disabled` bindings are exactly the same, and I would like to put them at one place, in case we need to modify them, or add other attributes that apply to all three variants.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'sharedAttrs'
})
export class SharedAttrsDirective {
  @HostBinding('class')
  protected readonly clz = classes;

  @HostBinding('attr.disabled')
  protected isDisabled() {
    return someBoolean;
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  protected handleClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    doStuffWith(event);
  }
}
```

Then in your template, you can do something like:

```html
<button sharedAttrs></button>

<a sharedAttrs href="www.stackoverflow.com"></a>
<some-other-element-or-component sharedAttrs></some-other-element-or-component>
```

Comment: Hmm, a Directive does sound promising. But the `classes` and `disabled` are currently `@Input`-bindings and getter-methods in my `button.component.ts`. How do I pass those values to the directive?